# Facebook Page plugin - White screen of death

Tags: html, facebook, angular, ionic-framework

I have been working in a Ionic1 app where i included the facebook page plugin iframe code (To include Like Page Widget to my app).

The fb link from where i get the code for page plugin is

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Now after i included the iframe in my app, i am getting the facebook like Widget and once i clicked in the like 'Like myPage' button, its asking for Confirmation. After clicking confirm button, i am getting a blank screen with '1'. Anyone kindly tell what this error tells about?

My iframe code included in Ionic3 app is,

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMyCompanyName-ID%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=256&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId=MyappID" width="340" height="256" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is advisable not to use Facebook Like Functionality from page plugin. The reason for facebook tells about the white screen of death is about the permissions in corresponding page(Age/country). But after this also i cant able to overcome white screen error.

As per Fb docs,
You cannot like a facebook page but you can like posts and images.

So if your app is huge fan based, don't go for page plugin instead redirect the user to the page url where they can acheive the functionality.

Remember, at odd times, fb page plugins doesn't shows the white screen of death. This doesn't means that page plugin started working in your app. Better use redirect page url as advised!

Comment: The same plugin is working in Websites. How come it works in websites?

Comment: The reason is fb checks whether the user is logged in to fb in web browsers and it performs the process. However for ionic app, fb page plugin doesn't knows about the login status so user is asked to send the login access token. There comes the null exception scenario. Since my old account is blocked, i can't able to provide the previously answered question links to you. Sorry for that! Approve and upvote if you find this helpful!

Comment: Will adding access token to the request, rectifies the blank screen error in page plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Alice said, Fb yet to solve the query for 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closed' of null
which probably calls the white screen of death. It is not possible to use page plugin since your page pop up is closed for your page.

Instead redirect user to the page url of facebook for tre functionalities.

The reason behind the working of plugin in websites after removing age/country restrictions is that the user's logged in in the browser and so the fb authenticate from the login session..

If the user is not logged in, it is not possible for the plugin to like page in websites.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you will be having the same doubts which i had over page plugin.
Let me give some info from my side
- You will be facing a 1 error. 1 denotion calls close-popup.php which is actually designed for websites(php). So, for websites, when the facebook page plugin returns 1, the popup from facebook which is openend gets closed.
- This is where you get a blank screen in mobile app developoment.
- You are getting success response as 1 from facebook but the closepopup.php will not be available to close the window. There comes a infinite opened blank screen with error 1. Commonly known as White screen of death in php.
- also in websites, cookies needs to be enabled which cant be acheived in mobile
- For the purpose only, fb docs says that you cannot use the page like from mobile apps instead you can like posts and shares.
- Meanwhile, you can file a bug report to Facebook to get more insights into the problem.